# Reduce Findstr Output

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

I want to reduce the Output of the following Line:
`for /F "tokens=10" %a in ('c:\Programme\smartmontools\bin\smartctl.exe -a /dev/hdb ^| findstr  /BC:"  9" ') do @echo %a`

This line is extracting the Power-On-Hours Value from an HDD or SSD.

Most HDDs or SSDs give me the correct hours like: 3423 or something. Just the simple Value.

Unfortunately, some Kingston SSDs have the following Value: 197h+00m+00.000s

Is it possible to reduce the Output to 197 ?

Maybe with another findstr pipe?

The Command must be in the same line (!) like something:
This does not work, but I hope it explains what I mean by that.

```
for /F "tokens=10" %a in ('c:\Programme\smartmontools\bin\smartctl.exe -a /dev/hdb ^| findstr  /BC:"  9" | findstr [0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?') do @echo %a
```

Sorry for my bad english!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findstr` can find a line containing a certain string, but it isn't able to modify the line.

You can add another `for` to do what you want:

```
@for /F "tokens=10" %a in ('@c:\Programme\smartmontools\bin\smartctl.exe -a /dev/hdb ^| findstr  /BC:"  9" ')  do @for /f "delims=h" %b in ("%a") do @echo %b
```

(unverified, as I don't have this utility)

Comment: Good Job, thank you! But.... i have to put this line into a zabbix Userparameter and the output looks like this: C:\Windows\system32>for /F "delims=h" %b in ("197h+00m+00.000s") do @echo %b
197 . It is possible to suppress the output of the "c:\windows..." line?

Comment: I only need the 197

Comment: Perfect! 12 Points to Stephan! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Zabbix doesn't like the second stacked for. Since a typical (shortened) smartctl output looks like this:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   120   099   ---    Pre-fail  Always       -       235885189
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   098   097   ---    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       442
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   ---    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002f   085   060   ---    Pre-fail  Always       -       347745957
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   075   075   ---    Old_age   Always       -       197h+00m+00.000s
```

You can change the first `for /f` to include the letter `h` as a delimiter since there is no other lower case h on that line. So

```
for /F "tokens=10delims=h " %a in ('c:\Programme\smartmontools\bin\smartctl.exe -a /dev/hdb ^| findstr  /BC:"  9" ') do echo %a
```

Should output:

```
197
```

Comment: this was my first thought, but as I didn't know, what the output would look like... I personally would use `find "Power_On_Hours"` instead of `findstr /BC:"   9"` - just for readability.